# Why stresses on a flywheel are similar to a pressure vessel?

Tags: angular-momentum, continuum-mechanics

A spinning wheel or an engine car flywheel has the same maths, regarding the stresses developed when spinning, with a pressure vessel

Maybe someone knows the underlying mechanism for this similarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer rim of a flywheel must exert a radially inward force to keep the components of the wheel in circular motion. You could say this is similar to the radially inward force that must be exerted by the walls of a pressure vessel if there is a higher pressure inside than outside.

However, the analogy disappears when you consider the upper and lower surfaces of a flywheel. The force that the upper and lower surfaces exert must still be directed radially inward towards the axis of rotation, and varies linearly with distance from this axis, whereas the upper and lower walls of a cylindrical pressure vessel must exert a vertical force that is constant per unit area.

I don't believe any underlying mechanism is required to explain this partial analogy.